# SQL Server : combine 2 SELECTS with JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2014

I am trying to get 2 sets of queries into one call and I can not seem to get it correct.

The data I am calling is this:

[image]

The query for each table is this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    tT 
WHERE 
    active = 1 
    AND ADate BETWEEN '01/03/2011' AND '09/01/2012' 
    AND (RID = 0...etc etc....
```

AND

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    tE 
WHERE 
    active = 1  
    AND  (RID = 0...etc etc...
```

I've tried my best to combine them:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT * 
     FROM tT 
     WHERE active = 1  
       AND ADate BETWEEN '01/03/2011' AND '09/01/2012' 
       AND (RID = 0...etc etc..
JOIN
    (SELECT * 
     FROM tE 
     WHERE active = 1 
       AND (RID = 0...etc etc...  ) ON tT.RID = tE.RId
```

But that returns only 11 rows when it should be double that (22).

How can I combine both and also get the full 22 rows?

Comment: Your sample data has no dates at all, and you still get 11 rows? Amazing!

Comment: .... its going off of the RID = XX, etc...

Comment: have you tried to change JOIN with UNION ALL ?

Comment: Are you simply trying to combine the results of these two queries?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think you should describe desired output. There a lot of statements to 'combine' data in MS SQL (2 kinds of `UNION`, 4 kinds of `JOIN`)

Comment: Yes thats what I am trying to do @RH6

Comment: It would be so much easier to answer if you would share the design of the 2 tables and tell us which fields you want in the combined result and which fields you do not

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just combine the results of the two queries, simply perform a union on the two.

```
SELECT * FROM tT WHERE active = 1 AND ADate BETWEEN '01/03/2011' AND '09/01/2012' AND (RID = 0...etc etc..
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tE WHERE active = 1 AND (RID = 0...etc etc...
```

If you don't want to include duplicate records, remove 'ALL' from the union statement and only unique records will be returned.

Comment: When putting that in I get an error of **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.**

Comment: Got it but like I stated in another comment, it does not have the same number of columns and different column names.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to combine that data from the 2 tables than use union.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tT 
WHERE  active = 1 
AND    ADate BETWEEN '01/03/2011' AND '09/01/2012' 
AND    (RID = 0...etc etc..

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
FROM   tE 
WHERE  active = 1 
AND    (RID = 0...etc etc...
```

But this will only work if both tables have the exact same fields, of exact the same type.

If that is not the case than you cannot do select * but you should name and if needed convert your fields...
For example: (not knowing your fields I just took some random names)

```
SELECT tT.ID, tT.Field1, tT.TypeID
FROM   tT 
WHERE  active = 1 
AND    ADate BETWEEN '01/03/2011' AND '09/01/2012' 
AND    (RID = 0...etc etc..

UNION ALL

SELECT tE.KeyID as ID, tE.Field2 as Field1, convert(int, tE.TypeCode) as TypeID
FROM   tE 
WHERE  active = 1 
AND    (RID = 0...etc etc...
```

**EDIT**
**If both table are not matching at all you have to be more creative.**
For example:
tT has fields ID int, Field1 int, Field2 varchar(10) and Field3 int
tE has fields ID int, field4 int, field5 varchar(10) and Field6 datetime

content would be for example :

```
tT
ID     Field1    Field2    Field3
--     ------    ------    ------
1      30        test      40

tE
ID     Field4    Field5    Field6
--     ------    ------    ------
2      50        hello     30/04/2017
```

the result should be

```
ID     Field1    Field2    Field3    Field6
--     ------    ------    ------    ------
1      30        test      40        
2      50        hello               30/04/2017
```

The query would than be

```
SELECT tT.ID, tT.Field1, tT.Field2, tT.Field3, null as Field6
FROM   tT 
WHERE  active = 1 
AND    ADate BETWEEN '01/03/2011' AND '09/01/2012' 
AND    (RID = 0...etc etc..

UNION ALL

SELECT tE.KeyID as ID, tE.Field4 as Field1, tE.Field5 as Field2, null as Field3, tE.Field6
FROM   tE 
WHERE  active = 1 
AND    (RID = 0...etc etc...
```

If you would share your table design I could make query that fits better to your needs...

Comment: @StealthRT It would be so much easier to answer if you would share the design of the 2 tables and tell us which fields you want in the combined result and which fields you do not

Comment: @StealthRT I added an example of how to use union when both tables have different fields.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are trying to do

```
CREATE TABLE #Test(
RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
Texts VARCHAR(50)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE #Test1(
RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
Numb  INT
)
GO

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('Test')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('Best')
GO

INSERT INTO #Test1 VALUES (34)
INSERT INTO #Test1 VALUES (35)
GO

SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM #Test )T
JOIN
(SELECT * FROM #Test1)T1
ON T.RowID = T1.RowID
```

Comment: That would work but I have different columns in each table so they dont match up. AKA **All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.**

Comment: @StealthRT if you are to use a `Join` the two tables that you wish to join should have at-least one column similar. In that case I hope the above code would work.. Maybe I have not understood your query well enough.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly following query should work.
Suppose you have **col1 & col3** in **table tT** whereas **col1 & col2** in **table tE** then you should use null as before the column which is not present

```
SELECT col1, null as col2, col3
FROM   tT 
WHERE  active = 1 
AND    ADate BETWEEN '01/03/2011' AND '09/01/2012' 
AND    (RID = 0...etc etc..

UNION ALL

SELECT col1, col2, null as col3
FROM   tE 
WHERE  active = 1 
AND    (RID = 0...etc etc...
```

Let me know in case nay thing else is required.